# ASP.NET/GridView: HeaderStyle-CssClass has no effect

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

I have the following GridView in ASP.NET 3.5:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTable" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" ShowHeader="true">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityDate" HeaderText="Date"
      HeaderStyle-CssClass="date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityType" HeaderText="Type" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityNotes" HeaderText="Notes" />
  </Columns>
  <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" Mode="NextPrevious" PageButtonCount="5"
    PreviousPageText="Older activities" NextPageText="Newer activities" />
</asp:GridView>
```

What I'm trying to do is have the first cell of the `<thead>` of the table to have the CSS class `"date"`. However, it seems to have no effect whatsoever. If I use `ItemStyle-CssClass`, it does have the wanted effect, but applies to all of the body cells as well.

What am I doing wrong?

The HTML it gives me looks like this:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"> <!-- No class :( -->
      Date
    </th>
    ...
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: How is your CSS defined?

Comment: @Shawn: What do you mean? (I don't see how that could matter anyways?)

Comment: what is in the css class for "date"? It might give us a clue to why it's not working.

Comment: It only has a width set. I know it works, because I use it in my currently static tables.

Comment: Do you have anything else that overrides your css?  anything set for generic th or td elements?

Comment: What does the source html gives you?

Comment: @adrianos: No. @joerage: Added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an outdated version of the CSS Friendly Control Adapters. Downloaded the latest source, compiled, used the new DLL and .browser file and that fixed it.